# Tailwind - Footer is not sticky and push by when neibouring element is overflow

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

Trying several solution from sourceforge seem cannot found it. Appreciate if somebody can found the link to the solution

Issue:
I have 3 flex column element

- Sub Header
- Main (with overflow-y-auto)
- Sub Footer

Somehow when main content is overflow, the Sub Footer is push down beyond screen size.
Where do I missed ?

The codes:
https://play.tailwindcss.com/GHQWK3Fxw1

Comment: did you add postition: sticky; to it? i didnt notice that on your footer

Comment: @Dev I try add .sticky .bottom-0 for Sub Footer element but still the whole container height is larger than the screen. If I remove some of the text content from the content so it not overflow, the whole layout look fine and I can see the Header, Sub Header and Sub Footer in one screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The outer container should be `max-h-screen` and then set the proper overflow. Because the `Mainscreen` div is `flex` it will fill the height of it's `max-h-screen` parent.

```
<div class="container w-screen bg-green-100">
    <div class="flex flex-col max-h-screen w-full overflow-hidden">
        <!-- Start Header -->
        <div class="py-3 bg-gray-700 text-white text-center">Header</div>
        <!-- End Header -->
        <!-- Start Mainscreen -->
        <div class="flex flex-col mb-auto p-0 overflow-hidden">
            <div class="flex flex-row h-full w-full overflow-hidden">
                <div class="flex w-72 bg-yellow-100">Sidebar</div>
                <!-- Content -->
                <div class="flex w-full max-h-full flex-col overflow-auto">
                    <div class="py-2 bg-gray-100 text-gray-700 text-center">Sub Header</div>
                    <div class="h-full overflow-y-auto p-5"> What is Lorem Ipsum? Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of t ....</div>
                    <div class="py-5 bg-gray-700 text-center text-white">Sub Footer</div>
                </div>
                <!-- End Content -->
                <div class="flex w-72 bg-purple-100">Rightbar</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Mainscreen -->
    </div>
</div>
```

[Tailwind on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/z37vcDVvlq)

Comment: thank you, it fix the issues, would you like to give some logic on the fix? and point out what is my mistakes? -- Such as sidebar and rightbar doesn't need h-full and flow, or the reason max-h-screen is not on container ?

Comment: You could put max-h-screen on the outermost `container` but then you'd have to add h-full to it's child too. Therefore I'd use it on the parent that I want full viewport height instead of grandparent(s). Of course there are many ways.

Answer (score 2):

To make a footer sticky, you can use Flexbox.
First wrap your header, main, footer tags with a container/wrapper div. And then add `flex flex-col min-h-screen` classes to the container/wrapper.
And then add `flex-1` class to the main tag.

This will make the main/content grow as much as needed. Making it take all the space in the screen leaving some space for the header and footer as much as they need.

I have written a whole blog on this, check it out: https://developerwings.com/footer-stick-to-bottom-using-tailwind/